# How to properly implement HOC in React

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code to add a small animation on `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount`. However, I am doing something wrong since it is not working.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Animated, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

export const withAnimation = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return class extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        opacityValue: new Animated.Value(0),
      }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      console.log('hello')
      return Animated.timing(
        this.state.opacityValue, 
        {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 200,
          easing: Easing.ease,
          isInteraction: false,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }
      ).start();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      return Animated.timing(
        this.state.opacityValue, 
        {
          toValue: 0,
          duration: 100,
          easing: Easing.ease,
          isInteraction: false,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }
      ).start();
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <Animated.View style={[styles.flex1, { opacity: this.state.opacityValue }]}>
          <WrappedComponent/>
        </Animated.View>
      )
    }
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  flex1: {
    flex: 1,
  }
})
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Am I returning `WrappedComponent` correctly? I am using it as such `const enhancedComponent = withAnimation(OriginalComponent)`

Comment: I'm not too sure what not working means but my guess is that you're returning `Animated.timing...` in both `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount`

Comment: Yes, but I am also calling `start()` on them.

Answer (score 0):

Copied your code and it seems to be working on my side (tried on Android & iOS).

But from the sample code here, `Easing` seems to be missing from the import statement. Not sure if that's the cause (I've had experiences with RN where errors are not thrown when they're supposed to be)

By the way, generally speaking about implementing HOCs, you'll also need to pass down the props from the HOC to the wrapped component `<WrappedComponent {...this.props}/>`. For special use cases, you might need to do [ref-forwarding](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-in-higher-order-components) & [hoisting the static properties/methods of the wrapped component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#static-methods-must-be-copied-over) too.